# How to create a Makefile for a C++ project with multiple directories?

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to create a Makefile for a project with the following layout:

```
Source files (.cpp, potentially .c) in /src, with potential subdirectories
Header files (.h, .hpp...) in /inc, with potential subdirectories
Object files (.o) in /obj, with potential subdirectories
External libraries in /lib
Compiled program in /bin
```

So far, I've managed to write together this Makefile, but with some issues:

```
SRC_DIR     := src
BIN_DIR     := bin
LIB_DIR        := lib
INC_DIR        := inc
OBJ_DIR        := obj

SRCEXTS     := .c .C .cc .cpp .CPP .c++ .cxx .cp
HDREXTS     := .h .H .hh .hpp .HPP .h++ .hxx .hp

TARGETS        := $(BIN_DIR)/program
SOURCES        := $(wildcard $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR)/*,$(SRCEXTS)))
HEADERS        := $(wildcard $(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)/*,$(HDREXTS)))
OBJECTS        := $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SOURCES)))

CXX         = g++
CXXFLAGS     = -std=c++17 -c -g -Wall

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)%$(OBJECTS): $(SRC_DIR)%$(SOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGETS)
```

I've tried to make it as "generic" as possible, so future projects could be started with this layout and makefile as a template. Currently, it creates the .o-files inside the src-directory alongisde the source code. It also fails when trying to compile the program with

```
g++ src/main.o -o bin/program
/usr/bin/ld: src/main.o: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 3 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: src/main.o: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:23: bin/program] Error 1
```

Very new to C++ development. Been on a wild goose-chase for a while, trying to get a clear image of how it all works. My code is basically a weird Frankenstein monster of several code snippets I've stumbled upon. Hopefully my intentions are clear enough, this is my last ditch effort! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot. You need one Makefile per directory.

Comment: You say that `obj/` may have subdirectories. Does it have the same structure as `src/`? That is, if you have `src/sailboat/foo.c`, do you want Make to build `obj/sailboat/foo.o`?

Comment: Not so, @spectras.  It is entirely possible to use a single makefile to build a complex, multi-directory project.  In fact, [doing so has some distinct advantages](https://accu.org/journals/overload/14/71/miller_2004/).

Comment: Inasmuch as you are new both to C++ development and to `make`, I would suggest setting your sites lower.  The `make` program has been around a long time, and no one has yet managed a universal makefile.  This is an area addressed, to varying degrees, by higher-level tools such as IDEs and the Autotools.  Accept building objects alongside their corresponding sources, or learn about `VPATH` if you're uncomfortable with that.  Consider using explicit target lists instead of using wildcards.  Write a makefile specific to your project before trying to generalize.

Comment: @Beta, yes you are exactly right. But I guess in practice it doesn't matter? Objects are usually deleted after compiling if I've understood it correctly?

Comment: @JohnBollinger the link you sent seems very interesting! I've only skimmed through it, but it does seem like you say. This seems very much way too complex. I'll try and do as you say, and create the .o-files alongside their source file. However, do you see why it fails on what seems to be the last step of the compilation? Right now, it successfully creates the .o-file (inside the src/-directory, because of some error with my script lol). But when it calls "g++ src/main.o -o bin/program" it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnBollinger points out, you are attempting too much at once. I will suggest a few changes to get your makefile off the ground.

I can't explain the error you get when you try to build the executable (you haven't given us enough information to reproduce the error), but it doesn't look like a Make problem. I suggest you try to build it *without* Make, using the command line, and see what happens.

I will assume that the names of your sources end in ".cpp" (such as `src/sailboat/foo.cpp`), the names of your headers end in ".hpp", and the directory tree under `obj/` is already present and correct. These restrictions are temporary training wheels; you can remove them when you have more skill.

First, finding the source files. This:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR)/*,$(SRCEXTS)))
```

will not work if `src/` has subdirectories. To recurse into subdirectories, we will use `find`. (There is a shortcut available to GNUMake, but for now we'll do things the slow and careful way).

```
SOURCES := $(shell find src -name "*.cpp")
```

Now to construct the names of the desired object files, such as `obj/sailboat/foo.o`. This:

```
OBJECTS := $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SOURCES)))
```

will give you `src/sailboat/foo.o`. We need a different command to change the leading directory as well as the suffix:

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

Some of the source files refer to header files, so before we can start building objects, we must be able to supply them. The compiler can find the needed headers, but we must tell it where to search. So we need the directories, not the full paths:

```
HEADERS := $(shell find inc -name "*.hpp")
HEADERDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(HEADERS)))
```

(The `sort` is just to remove duplicates. Not necessary, but tidy.)

Now the rule to build the objects. **This is incorrect:**

```
$(OBJ_DIR)%$(OBJECTS): $(SRC_DIR)%$(SOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Remember that `OBJECTS` can contain several space-separated words. So if it contains `foo bar`, the target will be `obj/%foo bar`, which is clearly not what you intended. Likewise the prerequisite list is wrong, and the recipe too. Junk it and start over.

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -c -o $@
```

Then remember the header files, and add flags to tell the compiler where to look for them:

```
INCLUDEFLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(HEADERDIRS))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -c $(INCLUDEFLAGS) -o $@
```

That should be enough to get your makefile working; further refinements can wait.

Comment: Thanks man! This helped me find the answer, and explained some of the mistakes I made while trying to code this together. The only difference I made was this, after testing compiling the files through the terminal like you suggested:
`$(CXX) -c $(IFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)`
I think I got the order wrong with the flags and files before, which made the compiler send that error at me. It seems to work now at the very least! Will have to test .h-files later, but thanks nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not mastering makefiles but one thing for sure : target "all" is definitively not a PHONY target because it often depends on other targets (in fact, it always depends on other targets, by definition !).

Also, as said John Bollinger, it is obviously possible to have only one makefile at the root.

"all" target is not mandatory : make will look for the first target fisrt.

The folder structure is like this :

```
----root
    ----src
    ----inc
    ----obj
    ----lib
```

Here's a simple one of mine (rules to build static libraries have been commented out)  :

```
CC=g++

SRCDIR=./src/

INCDIR=./inc/
INCFLAG=-I$(INCDIR)

OBJDIR=./obj/

LIB=./lib/
LIBFLAG=-lstdc++
#-lmystaticlibrary -lmyclasses
#$(LIBFLAG) -L$(LIB)
#STATICLIBRARIES= mystaticlibrary myclasses
OBJECTS = $(OBJDIR)apprendre.o $(OBJDIR)myfunctions.o $(OBJDIR)myclasses.o 

apprendre: $(OBJECTS)
    @ echo
    @ echo --------------------- Edition des liens
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(INCFLAG)

# mystaticlibrary: mystaticlibrary.o
#   @ echo
#   @ echo --------------------- Compilation librairie statique $@
#   ar cr $(LIB)lib$@.a $(OBJ)$@.o
#   ranlib $(LIB)lib$@.a

# myclasses: myclasses.o
#   @ echo
#   @ echo --------------------- Compilation librairie statique $@
#   ar cr $(LIB)lib$@.a $(OBJ)$@.o
#   ranlib $(LIB)lib$@.a

$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp $(INCDIR)myfunctions.h $(INCDIR)myclasses.h 
    @ echo
    @ echo --------------------- Compilation $<
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCFLAG) -o $@

run:
    @ echo
    @ echo "-----------------------> GO !!! : apprendre"
    @ ./apprendre
```